# df.dropna() not dropping rows with na

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove all the rows from dataframe where column "colImp" has no value and convert it to int type. Its a very simple code but I can still see 'nan' after doing dropna. Below is the code.

```
df[colImp] = df[colImp].astype(str).str.strip().replace('', np.nan).replace('\.0', '', regex=True)
df = df.dropna(axis = 0, subset=[colImp])
df[colImp] = df[colImp].astype(int)
```

The 3rd step step gives error "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'nan'". When I checked I could see nan's in the dataframe. Can someone please help what is going wrong over there.

Comment: Do you have a sample value for ```colImp```? my guess is the first line might not be matching correctly, and ```dropna()``` isn't doing what you expect.

Comment: Shouldn't your replace statements be the other way round? (i.e. ".replace('\.0', '', regex=True).replace('', np.nan)" instead of ".replace('', np.nan).replace('\.0', '', regex=True)") otherwise you could still be left with some blank strings that aren't converted to np.nan.

Comment: @KJDII the column values are all integers but when I read them into df, they could even be a float or string sometime (because of the way other team has saved the excel and sent me over). The values are like: 1790760387, 1790760387, 1205811890, 1538291547

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something like this work:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'colImp':[2,'',2.7,'5123123']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['colImp'] = pd.to_numeric(df['colImp'], errors='coerce')
df = df.dropna(subset=['colImp'], axis=0)
df['colImp'] = df['colImp'].astype(int)

print(df)

    colImp
0        2
2        2
3  5123123
```